# Full clone from one host to another

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clone, disk-image, disk-cloning

I have a headless mini-pc running Ubuntu Server 18.04 - nothing special, just a "Beelink Gemini X55" 8GB RAM, 128Gb SSD.  Its benchmark's are quite impressive compared to VPS alternatives and even some production enterprise servers where I work.

It's currently hosting my live website.

I've just bought another X55 mini-pc - exactly the same hardware and specs - with the purpose of having using it as a development server.

I'd like to clone the existing production server, making an identical duplicate, changing only the hostname and static IP address entries etc.

What is the best way of doing this?  Are there some disk copying tools that can create an image from a live Linux operating system, which can then be used boot from the USB device on the new system, creating a bootable image?

I've successfully done this in Windows using "Macrium Reflect" which handles VSS copying.  However, as far as I'm aware, there is no Linux alternative.

I don't run a GUI on this machine so whatever solution I end up using will need to be command line based only.

Comment: Do you want to clone a running system without interruption (because if it is allowed to stop services the task is very easy)? Do you use a volume management on a remote system, like LVM, ZFS?

Comment: Have you tried [fsarchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/quickstart/) ?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov - Yes, this clone would be made from a running system (added complication I know)  No volume management.  I could stop services temporarily but would prefer not to.

Comment: Then block-level clone (dd and friends) will be in the best case screwed, in the worst case - unusable due to file system corruption (only in the clone). I can suggest a file-level clone procedure. For linux system, it is completely enough.

Comment: Could this work... backing up using something like `rsnapshot` to NAS, then start new server with Live distro USB, restoring to the new server directly from the NAS backup?

Answer (score 2):

There is "no Linux alternative" because Linux has such essential capability built-in, without any third-party software. You have to go through a few steps, though.

Let's assume you're "sitting at" the machine, which I'll call "local", and you need to configure it as a clone of another, "remote" system.

On a new machine you just boot any Linux live CD (doesn't matter which one, if you need text-based one, use Gentoo install CD). Boot in the same mode as you will use everyday (choose UEFI or legacy BIOS; it is impossible to set up UEFI boot while booted with legacy).

Connect from it to the remote host, requesting a reverse port forwarding:

```
ssh remote-host -R 12345:localhost:12345
```

this will allow you later to send disk data over the network through this SSH connection. Then leave this console open, and switch to another console, where you will prepare local disk and run a reception command which unpacks network stream and writes files.

Prepare local disks to the desired structure. You can look up in the remote console how the origin system is partitioned, `lsblk`, `blkid` and `fdisk -l /dev/whatever` are your friends. As a result, these commands should give similar answers on both systems. Then mount root file system somewhere on the local (target) system, for example, to the `/mnt/newroot`:

```
mkdir /mnt/newroot
mount /dev/rootdeviceyouchose /mnt/newroot
cd /mnt/newroot
```

Now we are going to run receive and unpack commands. It looks like this:

```
netcat -l -p 12345 | tar -xpf -
```

It should "hang", because it is now waiting for data in the format of a tarball coming to the TCP port 12345 to be extracted (`-x`). It will also restore permissions (`-p`).

Switch to the remote (origin) console (where SSH is running) and prepare packing-and-sending:

```
mkdir /run/root-bind
mount --bind / /run/root-bind
cd /run/root-bind
tar -cpf - * | netcat localhost 12345
```

You can add `-v` (verbose) flag to both `tar`s to monitor the progress. Don't forget to clean up (`umount` and `rm` directory) after it's done.

It all looks like this (I copy temporary files from random server, but `/` would be copied exactly the same):

Receiving side:

```
merlin@muon /tmp/1 $ netcat -l -p 15151 | tar -xpvf - 
./debian-buster64/
./debian-buster64/linux
./debian-buster64/initrd.gz
./grub/
./grub/grub.cfg
./grubnetx64.efi.signed
./pxelinux.0
./pxelinux.cfg/
./pxelinux.cfg/default
```

Sending side:

```
merlin@muon ~ $ ssh ns -R 15151:localhost:15151
Linux ns 3.2.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.102-1 x86_64

merlin@ns:~$ cd tftp/
merlin@ns:~/tftp$ tar -cvpf - ./* | netcat localhost 15151
./debian-buster64/
./debian-buster64/linux
./debian-buster64/initrd.gz
./grub/
./grub/grub.cfg
./grubnetx64.efi.signed
./pxelinux.0
./pxelinux.cfg/
./pxelinux.cfg/default
```

Note, `--bind` is not recursive. If there were other file systems mounted under `/`, like `/boot`, `/var` and so on, these will not be copied through this act. Thus, after / you clone all other filesystems in the same way. It is possible to consolidate everything into a single fs using `--rbind` instead of `--bind`, but this might make next step harder.

You created filesystems anew, so you have to fix /etc/fstab on cloned system. `blkid` will show you new UUIDs, labels and so on, you have to replace old ones with new ones in the `/mnt/newroot/etc/fstab`. It is a good idea now to update IP address, host name and so on.

Now all files data is copied, fstab is fixed, and you need to recover a bootloader. In general, you `chroot` into system and reinstall a boot loader. Instructions how to do boot recovery depend on the distro you're using, and in general are available in their manuals. Also it depends on whether you use legacy BIOS boot or modern UEFI boot. I'm not sure if Debian instructions will do for Ubuntu, but it should work:

```
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/newroot/dev
mount --rbind /sys /mnt/newroot/sys
mount -t proc proc /mnt/newroot/proc
chroot /mnt/newroot
mount /dev/boot /boot # if it is a separate partition
mount /dev/device-for-esp /boot/efi # if you use an EFI System Partition
grub-install dummy # for UEFI
grub-install /dev/diskname # for legacy
update-grub
```

And reboot. It's done.

Comment: One remark. I just had same need, and successfully cloned a Debian system using exactly this method (I used my own answer here as a reminder.) The old system only needed some services (mysql) to be stopped for a brief period of time.

Answer (score 1):

For copying whole drives, usually `dd` is used, however it makes a bit-by-bit copy and thus even copies empty space, thus might be a bit slow:

```
dd if=/dev=sda of=dev/sdb
```

Where `sda` and `sdb` are the old and new drives, respectively.

Some say, `cat` was faster:

```
cat /dev/sda > /dev/sdb
```

`partclone` might be better suited, as it should only copy used blocks, and thus skip the problem of empty space:

```
partclone -b -s /dev/sda -o /dev/sdb
```

In all cases be very sure you know what `sda` and `sdb` is, you do not want to make a mess with your drives.... I'd also suggest, you make a bootable, headless live-usb and copy the drive while it is not live, or copy the non-root partitions while live and the rest while it is down, to reduce downtime of your server.

Comment: I'm not sure `dd` is the way to go, primarily because there's no easy way to mount the drive of the development server inth eproduction server without first building the development (OS / network config etc).  The drives in these miniPCs are soldered into the main boards so non-removable.

Comment: How about starting a live distro from a flash drive and do the copying from there? Even doing it via `ssh` should work then. Alternatively try to use what is going to be the future swap area for an intermediate installation and copy partitionwise and in the end erase the dummy OS and make it the swap

Comment: I have a NAS I can use to backup to and restore from - could I do this via a live distro?